# Кроссбраузерность и IE

Tags: html, html5, css3, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Возникла следующая проблема, на первых картинках различается шрифт в IE и  Chrome, на IE нет сглаживания что ли, шрифт менее аккуратный, хотя есть заголовки такого же шрифта и они отображаются нормально.

А на формах плейсхолдер почему то в IE съезжает вниз, но если там набрать что-то и удалить, то встает как надо + цвет текста не применился. Включены автопрефиксы в brackets. Не понимаю в чем проблема, может кто сталкивался с подобным ? Помогите :)

[image: IE]
[image: Chrome]
[image: Chrome]
[image: IE]

Comment: Еще бы ваш код а не скриншоты.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJPmrr - форма

Comment: в ие11 форма нормально отображается ) Так что указывайте еще версии браузеров в которых проверяете

Comment: я смотрю в IE 10, 

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpOGYd - кнопка 

Хотя форма на кодпене - нормально смотрится, а на сайте съезжает

Answer (score 0):

Съезжание инпутов поправил указанием высоты напрямую height: 40px в моем случае